# How to create multiple node environment?

Tags: node.js

For managing python, I maintain multiple environments using conda.

i.e. for a new project, I create a new environment new-project for my new python project.

`conda create -n new-project python=3.8`

However, it is not clear to me how I can create new node environemnt for my different nodejs projects.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54503474/3761628

Answer (score 0):

For node.js you can create your own `env` files that contain different values that better suites your environemnt

.env.test

```
API_KEY=TEST_API_KEY
```

.env.dev

```
API_KEY=DEV_API_KEY
```

to run node with this env variables

```sh
export $(xargs < ./env.test); node main.js;
```

and to access these variables in `main.js` file

```js
console.log(process.env.API_KEY);
```

more over, you most likely are usnig npm to manage your project so use `package.json` scripts to ease your life

package.json

```
"scripts": {
   "start:dev" : "export $(xargs < ./env.dev); node main.js;",
   "start:test" : "export $(xargs < ./env.test); node main.js;
}
```

then you only do

```sh
npm run start:dev
```

in case you are using `webpack` you can pass all `env` variables inside `configuration`