# How to use nvm in user-mode through Gitlab on Windows?

Tags: node.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, nvm, gitlab-runner

I use GitLab and I have several projects using different versions of node. I came across the [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) project, and installed it on my local machine to try it out.

```
$ nvm install 14.18.0
$ nvm use 14.18.0
```

raises an exception:

```
exit status 1: You do not have sufficient privilege to perform this operation.
```

I installed the `nvm` package without admin priviledges into the HOME directory, so no system path is involved. I believe that `mklink` is to blame here as this is used to create some symbolic links.

This would mean, that I need to run the Gitlab client in admin rights, but I want to avoid this. What would be the most common approach to use a pipeline with different node versions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57401522/2864740 — then use the “per-project local version”

Comment: Fantastic, I could accept this as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it has been said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869959/how-do-i-specify-a-local-version-of-node-for-a-project/57401522), just execute the following line and make sure it is git-tracked to solve the problem.

```sh
node --version > .nvmrc
```

and Add the following line to the `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
    "v": "node -v"
}
```