# Heroku Shopify Application Error 'npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, next.js, package.json

Greetings I have a problem with Heroku because it's don't want to install legacy packages for my Shopify app, my Shopify app is on Github and I just set up everything that my application needs, but when I deploy the main branch on Heroku I get this error in Heroku console below, can someone help me fix this?

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       USE_NPM_INSTALL=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 16.x...
       Downloading and installing node 16.14.0...
       Using default npm version: 8.3.1
       
-----> Restoring cache
       Caching has been disabled because NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
       npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
       npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! While resolving: shopify-app-node@1.0.0
       npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0
       npm ERR! node_modules/react
       npm ERR!   react@"^16.10.1" from the root project
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
       npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.2 || ^18.0.0-0" from next@12.0.10
       npm ERR! node_modules/next
       npm ERR!   next@"^12.0.2" from the root project
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
       npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
       npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! See /tmp/npmcache.CTfHl/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.CTfHl/_logs/2022-02-10T12_18_50_156Z-debug-0.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "shopify-app-node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Shopify's node app for CLI tool",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon ./server/index.js --watch ./server/index.js",
    "build": "NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1 next build",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./server/index.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.14.0",
    "npm": "8.4.1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-node.git"
  },
  "author": "Shopify Inc.",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/shopify/shopify-app-node/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.12.10",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/register": "^7.12.10",
    "@shopify/app-bridge-react": "^2.0.2",
    "@shopify/app-bridge-utils": "^2.0.2",
    "@shopify/koa-shopify-auth": "^4.1.2",
    "@shopify/polaris": "^6.2.0",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.9",
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "graphql": "^14.5.8",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "koa": "^2.13.1",
    "koa-bodyparser": "^4.3.0",
    "koa-compress": "^5.1.0",
    "koa-cors": "0.0.16",
    "koa-logger": "^3.2.1",
    "koa-router": "^10.0.0",
    "koa-session": "^6.1.0",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "next": "^12.0.2",
    "next-env": "^1.1.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.7",
    "react": "^16.10.1",
    "react-apollo": "^3.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.13.0",
    "slugify": "^1.6.5",
    "validator": "^13.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-stage-3": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "enzyme": "3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.15.6",
    "husky": "^4.3.6",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "prettier": "2.2.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "15.6.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.14.0"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,css,json,md}": [
      "prettier --write"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You appear to have conflicting dependencies. Do these same dependencies install cleanly on your local machine? What version of Node.js are you using? Is your `node_modules/` committed?

Comment: For nodejs I'm using 14.19.0 and for npm 8.4.0, and I try in my package.json to put "engines": {
    "node": "14.19.0",
    "npm": "8.4.0"
  }

Comment: I got same error when I do that

Comment: And what about my other two questions? (a) Does this project install cleanly locally using the lock file, e.g. with `npm ci`? (b) Is your `node_modules/` committed?

Comment: Note that the error message above says "Downloading and installing node 16.14.0", so it does not reflect your updated `package.json` requesting Node 14.

Comment: When I install locally I also needed to use "npm install --force", my node_modules is not committed to github

Comment: So I can remove the node version from engines in a package.json

Comment: "So I can remove the node version from engines in a package.json"—no, you should leave it in. Using different versions of Node in development and production can easily lead to problems. When you include the engines section, does Heroku use Node 14? That isn't shown above.

Comment: 'When I install locally I also needed to use "npm install --force"'—that's not what I asked. I asked if it works when you install _from the lock file_, e.g. using `npm ci`. Does `npm ci` work locally, with the exact lock file that you're trying to deploy?

Comment: When I use npm ci locally I get same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I install these old packages with `npm install --force`
2. I run `npm outdated`
3. I see what packages are in red
4. I do upgrade from the current version to the wanted version with `npm install --save packagename@wanted_version`
5. Remove any empty files that you may have in your project
6. Uploaded to git
7. Deploy to Heroku

Answer (score 11):

**If you cannot reproduce locally, set package.json `engines:` to match your local development**

This is not the OP's exact issue as they had specified `engines:` and reproduced locally, so definitely what they needed was to resolve it locally first, which is a subset of the infinite [Unable to resolve dependency tree error when installing npm packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages)

But I couldn't reproduce locally even after delting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, so as soon as I set `engines:`, which [Heroku respects](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version), to match my local working setup `node --version` and `npm --version` with:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.17.0",
    "npm": "6.14.13"
  },
```

it started working on Heroku. Here's my failing [package.json](https://github.com/cirosantilli/node-express-sequelize-nextjs-realworld-example-app/blob/e1817b39c7b5cd41d5b80ca3eb9ee64919016d40/package.json) to which the `engines` were added. The error was:

```
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
remote:        npm ERR! code ERESOLVE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
remote:        npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree                                                                                                                                                                                                              
remote:        npm ERR!                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
remote:        npm ERR! While resolving: conduit-node@1.0.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
remote:        npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/react                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
remote:        npm ERR!   react@"17.0.2" from the root project                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
remote:        npm ERR!                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
remote:        npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
remote:        npm ERR! peer react@"^16.11.0" from swr@0.3.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/swr                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
remote:        npm ERR!   swr@"0.3.0" from the root project
```

Prior to the fix, Heroku logs show it was using:

```
remote:        Downloading and installing node 16.14.0...                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
remote:        Using default npm version: 8.3.1
```

For this reason, you should Always, Always, set `engines` to match your local setup on a Heroku project.

Answer (score 5):

Ciro Santilli's way solved my problem:

I added these lines to package.json and the problem fixed:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x",
    "npm": "8.5.5"
  },
```

Apparently for me the "knex" module that I use is not compatible with newer npm (I am not sure).

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution. You can add config variables in Heroku apps.

Go to the app in Heroku -> settings -> Reveal Config Vars

Add a new config var with the key: `NPM_CONFIG_LEGACY_PEER_DEPS` and value `true`, and then redeploy.

Answer (score 3):

## You may use `.npmrc`

New versions of npm do not allow you to install dependencies with different versions of peer dependencies because it may  lead to breaking change. So if you are sure that everything works without any issues, maybe you have good tests. Just add `--legacy-peer-deps` or `--force` after your npm script (basically it's `npm i`). But it's so annoying to write it, instead you can create '.npmrc' file in the root of your project with following:

```
legacy-peer-deps=true
...
```

or even:

```
force=true
...
```

Now you don't need to add `--legacy-peer-deps` or `--force` manually.

ps. It also solves the problem with Heroku when you cannot explicitly use `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`. At least I don't know how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Your lock file contains conflicting dependencies. Since you were able to reproduce the error locally using [`npm ci`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-ci) we have a good way to test a fix locally.

It looks like you are depending directly on React 16. Is that something that you need directly, or is it just a dependency for Next.js?

If it's not something you need directly, [upgrade it per the Next.js docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-ci):

```
npm install react@latest react-dom@latest
```

That should modify your `package-lock.json`. Then try installing from the lock file again with `npm ci`. If that fixes things, commit the change and redeploy.

On the other hand, if you are directly depending on React 16 and cannot upgrade you'll have to consider rolling back to an earlier version of Next.js.

Comment: When I try npm install react@latest react-dom@latest I will get same thing

Comment: The exact same conflict? `peer react@"^17.0.2 || ^18.0.0-0" from next@12.0.10` and `react@"^16.10.1" from the root project`?

Comment: Yes sir, exactly that

Comment: @StefanMomcilovic, do you have a version constraint on React in your `package.json`?

Comment: It's look like this  "react": "^16.10.1",

Comment: `npm install react@latest react-dom@latest` should have updated your `package.json` as well as your `package-lock.json`. I currently get `^17.0.2`. Please update your question and show your entire `package.json`.

Comment: Updated question