# How to overwrite npm run build react app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, heroku

I connected my github repo with heroku so I can have deployments from there automatically. I created a react app and I have some dependecies that requires " npm install --legacy-peer-deps ", and when heroku is building the app, of course it doesn't use that command. How can I overwrite "npm install" with "npm install --legacy-peer-deps " ?
I tried to put in the package.json at scripts where is build insted of "react-scripts build ", I've put " react-scripts build && npm install --legacy-peer-deps" but it didn't work.

This is what it says in the error:

```
  npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
       npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
       npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `npm install --legacy-peer-deps && react-scripts build` try in a correct order. Also dependencies are already installed when build runs. Maybe try changing `npm install`

Comment: I got same error

Comment: Found a similar thread, check this out. Might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71067718/15443747

Answer (score 0):

I changed in package.json the version of npm to 6.14.9 and it worked and I also kept the npm install --legacy-peer-deps && react-scripts build

```
     "engines": {
    "node": "16.13.2",
    "npm": "6.14.9"
},
```