# Heroku deploy failing? Probably because of dependencies

Tags: heroku, npm-install

```
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
remote:        npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! While resolving: react-rss@2.0.1
remote:        npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/react
remote:        npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
remote:        npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
remote:        npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
remote:        npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^13.4.0" from the root project
remote:        npm ERR!   4 more (react-dom, react-router, react-router-dom, react-scripts)
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
remote:        npm ERR! peer react@"^16.13.1" from react-rss@2.0.1
remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/react-rss
remote:        npm ERR!   react-rss@"^2.0.1" from the root project
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/react
remote:        npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.13.1" from react-rss@2.0.1
remote:        npm ERR!   node_modules/react-rss
remote:        npm ERR!     react-rss@"^2.0.1" from the root project
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
remote:        npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
remote:        npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! See /tmp/npmcache.zVSUf/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.zVSUf/_logs/2022-11-03T19_15_38_788Z-debug-0.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: ea132e7d82ff4a3fe3121b0858e49a2c8336bec0
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version ea132e7d82ff4a3fe3121b0858e49a2c8336bec0
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to tb-work-hub.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/tb-work-hub.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

I don't understand this. It was working just fine yesterday. I'm guessing it's to do with some dependencies I was trying to work with?

If there isn't a clean solution, is there a good way to restore my app without having to start fresh, reinstall everything and copy-paste the src?

Tried: npm uninstall react-rss

Answer (score 0):

Go to the app in Heroku -> settings -> Reveal Config Vars

Add a new config var with the key: NPM_CONFIG_LEGACY_PEER_DEPS and value true, and then redeploy.

([Heroku Shopify Application Error 'npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71065040/heroku-shopify-application-error-npm-err-eresolve-unable-to-resolve-dependency))

I hope it works.